# Validator ругается "The document is not mappable to XML 1.0 due to two consecutive hyphens in a comment"

Tags: wordpress

Сайт на Wordpress, домен кириллица http://xn----htbeq0ay.xn--p1ai/ понял что на дефисы в домене ругается, а как-то обойти это можно, может кто знает?

Заранее благодарен за любые подсказки!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Это всего лишь предупреждение.
2. Зачем превращать html в xml?
3. **Просто не надо оставлять закомментированные куски кода на сайте.**